# Search query with table display

Tags: php, mysql

I have page table.php here' which has search which displays database table in table format. My code below can search and can display data but not in table format. Please help me code to make the display from search in table format.

```
   $output='';
   $noresult='';                                        
   //collect
   if (isset($_POST['search'])) 
    {
        $searchq = $_POST['search'];
        $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transaction where patientid like '%$searchq%' ") or die ("could not search");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($query);    

        if($count == 0)
        {
            $noresult = 'There was no search results!';
            } else 
                {           
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
                    {
                    $tranid = $row['tranid'];
                    $trandate = $row['trandate'];
                    $trandescription = $row['trandescription'];
                    $tranquantity = $row['tranquantity'];
                    $tranunitprice= $row['tranunitprice'];
                    $tranamount = $row['tranamount'];

                    $output .= '<div>'.$tranid.''.$trandescription.'</div>';
        }
      }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: This is simply a matter of echo'ing / displaying the html's table tags and etc, SO isn't a free coding service.

Comment: Go and look up the syntax for an HTML table. It isn't difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
echo "<table>
    <tr>
        <th scope='col'>id</th>
        <th scope='col'>date</th>
        <th scope='col'>description</th>
        <th scope='col'>quantity</th>
        <th scope='col'>unit price</th>
        <th scope='col'>amount</th>
    </tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "
        <tr>
            <td>".$row['tranid']."</td>
            <td>".$row['trandate']."</td>
            <td>".$row['trandescription']."</td>
            <td>".$row['tranquantity']."</td>
            <td>".$row['tranunitprice']."</td>
            <td>".$row['tranamount']."</td>
        </tr>
    ";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: thanks RamRaider I tried your code and it works. 

I been trying this for several days now. what comes out in my try is multiple table with 1 row each table. I cant post all the code here its too long that's why I shorten it comes out that question for easy understanding. Thanks a lot.

Comment: and am using bootstrap to have style in my table. i will first try figuring the code before i will ask for help in here. tthanks

Answer (score 0):

The below code should has to be implemented in else block.

```
                $ouput .= '<table>
                 <thead>
                  <tr>
                   <th>id</th>
                   <th>date</th>
                   <th>description</th>
                   <th>quantity</th>
                   <th>unit price</th>
                   <th>amount</th>                   
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>';

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
                {
                $row = "<tr>
                        <td>".$row['tranid']."</td>
                        <td>".$row['trandate']."</td>
                        <td>".$row['trandescription']."</td>
                        <td>".$row['tranquantity']."</td>
                        <td>".$row['tranunitprice']."</td>
                        <td>".$row['tranamount']."</td>
                        </tr>";

                $output .= $row;
                }
                $output .= "</tbody></table>";
                echo $output;
```

Comment: @Epodax Sorry for the syntax error in code and thanks for mentioning it